# Is it possible to get outer loop's key inside a nested loop? VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to get the outer loop's key inside the inner loops. Trying to get the radio button value with `selected[item.key]` but it doesn't work. It is possible to get the key of outer loop? or is that any better way to get the radio button value? The problem I encounter is that i was trying to get outer loop key as index of `selected` to store answer

```
<div v-for="(item,key) in items" :key="key">
 <div> {{ item.title }}</div>

 <div class="selections">  
   <div v-for="(selection,key) in item.selection" :key="key">
     <input type="radio" 
            v-model="selected[item.key] 
            :name=item.name" 
            :value="selection.name">
     <label :for="selection.name">{{selection.name}}</label
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

`selected` is an array ready to store those data.

```
item:[
   {name:"item1",id:"1",selection:[
                                   {id:1,name:"selection1"},
                                   {id:2,name:"selection2"},
                                   {id:3,name:"selection3"},
                                  ]
   },
   {name:"item2",id:"2",selection:[
                                   {id:1,name:"selection1"},
                                   {id:2,name:"selection2"},
                                   {id:3,name:"selection3"},
                                  ]
   },
   {name:"item3",id:"3",selection:[
                                   {id:1,name:"selection1"},
                                   {id:2,name:"selection2"},
                                   {id:3,name:"selection3"},
                                  ]
   },

]
```

Comment: your v-model has `selected` but in v-for its `selection` is this the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
   <div> {{ item.title }}</div>

   <div class="selections">  
      <div v-for="selection in item.selection" :key="selection.id">
         <input type="radio" 
               v-model="selected.find(({ id }) => id === item.id).name" 
               :name="item.name" 
               :value="selection.name">
         <label :for="selection.name">{{selection.name}}</label>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Or if you want to select the selection:

```
<div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
   <div> {{ item.title }}</div>

   <div class="selections">  
      <div v-for="selection in item.selection" :key="selection.id">
         <input type="radio" 
               v-model="item.selection.find(({ id }) => id === selection.id).name" 
               :name="item.name" 
               :value="selection.name">
         <label :for="selection.name">{{selection.name}}</label>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```